# How to delete pipelines when removing a branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

is there a way to delete pipelines of certain branch when removing the branch in gitlab?

As I know there is API but using it I can remove only one by one.

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: " -XDELETE
```

But it’s not convenient. Maybe there is another way to automate deleting?

Answer (score 0):

just create a scheduled pipeline like this

```
script:
  - |
    curl GET all pipelines
    filter the output by branches
    curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: " -XDELETE all the filtered pipelines
```

I didn't posted the entire code because do you know how to use the api.